# Simple trigonometrical equations

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

I'm having difficulties in solving the simultaneous equations
$$
\begin{cases}
\sin(x+y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
\cos(2x+y)=\frac12
\end{cases}
$$
for $0^{\circ}\le x,y\le 90^{\circ}$.

The answer is $x=15^{\circ}$ degrees and $y= 30^{\circ}$.

Comment: hint $$2x+y=x+(x+y)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x+y=45$

$2x+y=60$
Solving, we get $x=15, y=30$

Comment: Because $\sin(45)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $\cos(60)=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: you need the degree symbol $\circ$ = \circ all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin(x+y)=\dfrac1{\sqrt2}=\sin45^\circ$$

$x+y=n180^\circ+(-1)^n45^\circ$ where $n$ is any integer

As $0^\circ<x,y<90^\circ,0^\circ<x+y<180^\circ\implies x+y=45^\circ\  \ \  \ (1)$ or $x+y=135^\circ\  \ \  \ (2)$

Similarly, $2x+y=360^\circ m\pm 60^\circ$ where $m$ is any integer

As $0^\circ<2x+y<270^\circ,2x+y=60^\circ\  \ \  \ (3)$

Solve $(1),(3)$  and $(2),(3)$